# How to apply glPointSize(float) in Qt OpenGL?

Tags: qt, opengl, qwidget, glpointsize

I just started working on Qt OpenGL. I could draw some simple shapes on the screen with that. I need to draw points of various sizes on the screen in QWidget. I used standard `glPointSize(float)` for that. This does not seem to work. I wrote a command line program for that and in works just fine. Can any one help?

Comment: Also keep in mind that point size is in pixels and not units of any coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are doing this in a QGlWidget not a QWidget?
Did you remember glBegin(GL_POINTS)?

Do you mean you can't see the points or the size change has no effect?
The size value is arbitrary, sometimes you have to specify a much bigger value (10 or 20) to see any change from 1.

Comment: Yes, I am using QGLWidget. This is the line from my .h file:                          class GLWidget : public QGLWidget. I am using glPointSize(14.33). However, I can see only tiny dots on the screen.